# How to multiply one column to few other multiple column in Python DataFrame

Tags: python, dataframe, multiplication

I have a Dataframe of 100 Columns and I want to multiply one column `('Count')` value with the columns position ranging from 6 to 74. Please tell me how to do that.
I have been trying

```
df = df.ix[0, 6:74].multiply(df["Count"], axis="index")
df = df[df.columns[6:74]]*df["Count"]
```

None of them is working

The result `Dataframe` should be of 100 columns with all original columns where columns number 6 to 74 have the multiplied values in all the rows.

Answer (score 1):

You can multiply the columns in place.

```
columns = df.columns[6:75]
df[columns] *= df['Count']
```